# If I select mutiple objects, I can only sculp one of them

Tags: objects, sculpting, select

If I select multiple objects, I can only sculpt one of them. If I go to sculpt mode I can only sculpt the last object that I have selected. The outlines of the last selected one is yellow and the others are orange.

Answer (score 3):

You can sculpt more than one object but you need to make sure to uncheck the option Lock Object Modes, letting you select each and switch to sculpt mode.
[image]

You will still need to select the object you want to sculpt, but they will both be possible to sculpt without going back to Object mode for each.

If you want to sculpt both objects without needing to select them, then you will want to join them together as one object until you are done with sculpting - be careful because this means you may have to reassign materials or modifiers, etc.